# How Python treats numbers with 0 at the beginning?

Tags: python, math, calculator

I want Python recognize numbers like 030 as 30. for some reason, when I write "print 030" it returns 24, when I write "print 020" it returns 16. What's the reason and How can I make it treat it as 30?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

> How can I make it treat it as 30?

Just write `30` normally, or if you accept this number as a string,

```
>>> int('030')
30
```

will work just as expected.

Comment: +1, because it's THAT easy, and python isn't python without easy stuff ;)

Comment: +1. Didn't knew that. Deleted my answer.

Answer (score 0):

A leading 0 signals 'octal' format, i.e. base 8.

```
print "0{}".format(30)

--output:--
030
```

> How can I make it treat it as 30?

You can never make python 2.x treat 030 as 30.

Comment: What is that `print` statement even supposed to prove?

Comment: When someone unfamiliar with octal format writes "print 030", is it inconceivable to you that they may want to print 30 with a leading 0?

Comment: It was inconceivable until you pointed it out but now I see where you are coming from

Answer (score 0):

most languages treat numbers starting with 0 as octal numbers, so 30 octal = 3 * 8 = 24

Answer (score 0):

One way that I could think of is this.

```
n='030'
n=n[1:]
n=int(n)
```

Now n has the number that can be treated like integer 30